# Can't link shared library in cmake due to image not found

Tags: c, cmake, linker, shared-libraries, bazel

I am trying to include a bazel built shared library in my cmake project. I was able to find the library, as you can see in the terminal output, but as soon as I want to link it, I get the *image not found* error. I know that it should be realted to a rpath and OSX in general, but I can't figure out my problem. I hope someone can help me out! Thanks!

##### CMakeLists.txt:

```
    cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20.0)
    
    project(test)
    add_executable(main.o main.c)
    
    execute_process(
        COMMAND bazel build //:all
        WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/lyra
    )
    
    execute_process(
        COMMAND bazel info bazel-bin
        WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/lyra
        OUTPUT_VARIABLE LYRABINDIR
        OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE
    )
    
    find_library(ENCODER_LIB lyra_encoder PATHS ${LYRABINDIR})
    message("Found Library at: ${ENCODER_LIB}")
    
    target_link_libraries(main.o PUBLIC "${ENCODER_LIB}")
```

##### Output:

[image]

Comment: Using **images** for code and logs are highly discourages on Stack Overflow. Instead, paste them as a text (with code formatting). See also [ask].